# JQuery function with multiple parameters reply undefined after first answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am modifying from a bot on [Github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smooch/smooch-bot-example/master/script.js). The bot can ask for a user's name and then reply "Great! I'll call you ${name}".

I've modified the bot to ask for a user's name and email. The question is how to get the bot to reply with those values (eg. "Your name is ${name} and email is ${email}").

```
response: {
    receive: (bot, message) => {
        return bot.getProp(`name`,`email`)
            .then((name,email) => bot.say(`value1:${name} \nvalue2:${email}`));
        }
},
```

Right now the response I am getting is:

"Value 1: Joe 
 Value 2: undefined"

What should I do to get it to answer value 1 and 2 correctly in one sentence? 
Thanks in advance for any help / pointers.

Comment: Where's the code for `.getProp()`?

Comment: Also, how does this have anything at all to do with jQuery?

Comment: I have no idea what code this is for, it's clearly not js nor jquery.  Having said that, `getProp` **clearly** takes a single argument, so maybe you can chain it like `bot.getProp('name').then((name) => bot.getProp('email').then ((email) => bot.say('${name} / ${email}')))`

Comment: sorry, I am not a programmer...I wasn't sure either. The keywords/pattern/explanation seemed to fit alot of jquery / javascript tutorials so I assumed...

@Pointy: I thought getProp is get property?  Sorry, I do not understand what do you mean by where's the code?  I am modifying a script from Github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smooch/smooch-bot-example/master/script.js

Comment: @freedomn-m:  Thank you so much for your suggestion!  It works!!  I've been trial & error this thing for a whole day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `getProp` takes a single argument, so you can chain it like this:

```
bot.getProp('name')
   .then((name) => 
       bot.getProp('email')
          .then ((email) => 
              bot.say('${name} / ${email}')))
```

`Name` will stay in context of the `.then((name) =>` while you get the next property.